# Commenting bug?

Tags: support, comments

I cannot give comments on SO but my rep is over 1000.

Is this a bug?

EDIT: Thank you guys: I thought I am going insane seeing this problem :)

I just don't see a link to make comments at all. Page seems to be fully loaded. I use Firefox 3.5. For example in this post I do not see anything that allows me to make a comment.

EDIT2: One more note. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225505/retaining-an-object-created-in-an-nsthread) post I am able to click on **add / show 3 more comments** in answer from Tom Dalling and comment box just appears.

EDIT3: In pure HTML link for inserting comments are in body. So it's JS error. Is there a way to get not minified version of JS?

EDIT4: Now I am in work. In Firefox 3.5.2 even with 'CTRL-F5` I still have **no comment** link available. If I use IE from same machine comments links are available.

EDIT5: I just home on Firefox 3.5 on Mac. And I have comments link. What is wrong with mu PC in work ...

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you told that you need more rep, or are the comments just not getting posted?

Comment: A link to the post you're attempting to comment on would also help

Comment: $5 on jQuery error

Comment: But jQuery is infallible!

Comment: The only thing that can fix jQuery is more jQuery...

Comment: I heard you like jQuery so I loaded your jQuery with jQuery so you can use jQuery while you load jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Turn noscript off, and make sure you do a complete reload of the page (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>).

Comment: Poor Rich B of -1. +10 ;)

Comment: I am just typing from home where I use Safari and as you see it works. I will check tomorrow from work where I use Firefox.

Comment: Crippling your browser does have that nasty problem of causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Is the page loaded all the way? I notice I cannot make any comments or answers until all components of the page have loaded. It is normaly the ads taking a bit to load.

Comment: Well Meta *is* the place for bug reports, so I do think that this is the right place for it.